# Changes Log Google Sheets / Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have had a look online and on previosuly asked questions but have not come across anything that is suited.

Essenitally I am looking for a script that populates a changes log of when a cell is edited.

I would like to keep a log of the previous comment, updated comment, user of who changed the cell and a timestamp

Any help / advice would be appreciated

Thank you

previoulsy used below; but it does not like the source

```
function edit(e) {
  
  

    var logsheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Change Log');
      
      var esheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      var ecell = esheet.getActiveCell();
      var ecol = ecell.getColumn();
      var erow = ecell.getRow();
      var editor = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
      var newcontents = ecell.getValue();
      var origValue = e.oldValue
      var Avals = logsheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues();
      var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
      var maxRows = logsheet.getMaxRows();
      
      logsheet.getRange(Alast+1,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd"/"mm"/"yy hh:MM');
      logsheet.getRange(Alast+1,2).setValue(editor);
      logsheet.getRange(Alast+1,3).setValue(esheet.getName());
      logsheet.getRange(Alast+1,4).setValue(ecell.getA1Notation());
      logsheet.getRange(Alast+1,5).setValue(origValue);
      logsheet.getRange(Alast+1,6).setValue(newcontents);
     
    
    }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look into [StackOverflow: How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to get a prompt response you can summarize the title and what's actually your expected code behavior. It's helpful for the community. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Most likely you will want to use the onEdit trigger and either log the edit information into a log file or a spreadsheet.  Everything beyond that is application specific.

Comment: Thank you, uploaded what i used previoulsy but it does not like the variable esheet = e.source

Comment: you can't run it without an event object ie without a trigger

Comment: Yes it has a trigger but the script has an error with the source:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined

Comment: Perhaps you left out the e in the function declaration

Comment: Did you get the answer? I'm sure you got the error because you tried to run the script from Script Editor. The function didn't get the event object, this why it couldn't get the source (a property of the event object). Event object is  appearing only when the function (trigger) `onEdit()` fires via changes on your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine(*). Here is example of output on the sheet 'Change log':

[image]

All you need is to rename the function from `edit(e)` to `onEdit(e)`.

And it doesn't work from Script editor of course. It fires only when you edit the table.

(*) Except `editor` column, perhaps. `onEdit()` may not be able to get editor names due the restrictions for simply triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

> They may or may not be able to determine the identity of the current user, depending on a complex set of security restrictions.